# iOS Charts not showing Y values

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am writing an iOS App in Swift 4.2. I am using [Charts Library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) to display Horizontal Bar chart. When I open the sample project, it shows the Y Values but, in my project it isn't showing the Y values. I copied the exact code from its sample.

**Sample screenshot:**
[image]
Observe 8.0, 14.0, 4.0, 10.0

**My screenshot:**
[image]

**My Code:**

```
 @IBOutlet weak var chartView: HorizontalBarChartView!

 func setupCharts(){

        chartView.noDataTextColor=UIColor(hex:UIConstants.Graphics.BrandTheme.ThemeColor)
        chartView.noDataText = "Chart_NoDataText".localized

        chartView.chartDescription?.enabled = false
        chartView.dragEnabled = false
        chartView.setScaleEnabled(true)
        chartView.pinchZoomEnabled = false
        //chartView.delegate = self
        chartView.drawBarShadowEnabled = false
        chartView.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = true
        chartView.maxVisibleCount = 60
        chartView.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(4)
        chartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled=false
        chartView.extraRightOffset=CGFloat(24)
        chartView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        chartView.legend.enabled=false
        chartView.fitBars = true

        let xAxis = chartView.xAxis
        xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
        xAxis.labelFont =  UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 11)!
        xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
        xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        xAxis.granularity = 1
        xAxis.enabled=true

        //
        let leftAxis = chartView.leftAxis
        leftAxis.labelFont =  UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 10)!
        leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
        leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
        leftAxis.enabled=false


        let rightAxis = chartView.rightAxis
        rightAxis.labelFont =  UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 10)!
        rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
        rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        rightAxis.axisMinimum = 0
        rightAxis.enabled = false

    }




func setChartDataWithValues(_ count: Int, values:[Double], labels:[String]) {

    let yVals = (0..<count).map { (i) -> BarChartDataEntry in

        let val = values[i]

        return BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: val)
    }

    let barChartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: yVals, label: "MF")

    barChartDataSet.drawIconsEnabled = false
    barChartDataSet.colors=[UIColor(hex: UIConstants.Graphics.BrandTheme.ThemeColor)]


    let data = BarChartData(dataSet: barChartDataSet)
    data.setValueFont(UIFont(name:"Lato-Regular", size:10)!)
    data.setValueTextColor(UIColor(hex:UIConstants.Graphics.BrandTheme.ThemeColor))

    let xAxis = chartView?.xAxis
    xAxis?.setLabelCount(3, force: false)
    xAxis?.valueFormatter=IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: labels )

    chartView?.data = data

}
```

**Calling:**

```
self.setChartDataWithValues(3,values:values, labels: ["Mutual Funds","Fixed Deposits","Savings Account"].reversed())
```

Comment: match your code with the example code to verify whats missing.

Comment: Everything is same

Comment: @AtifShabeer please post some code here.

Comment: @AtifShabeer try this modification https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612972/10150796

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani I have done these already, not working :(

Comment: Please post your code, without it we can't help you. The function that should do it is setDrawValues on the chart data.

Comment: @LorenzOliveto. Added code. Kindly check

Comment: @sohanvanani.  Added code. Kindly check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `data.setDrawValues(true)` when you create the `BarChartData`:

```
...
let data = BarChartData(dataSet: barChartDataSet)
data.setDrawValues(true)
data.setValueFont(UIFont(name:"Lato-Regular", size:10)!)
data.setValueTextColor(UIColor(hex:UIConstants.Graphics.BrandTheme.ThemeColor))
...
```

For version `3.2.1` of `Charts` you also need to remove this line because values are not rendered if `drawIconsEnabled` is false

```
barChartDataSet.drawIconsEnabled = false
```

Comment: values is Array of Int/Double example 11110,22200,239990

Comment: What version of Charts are you using? I created a sample project with your code and I can see the values on the right of the bars.

Comment: I am using Version 3.2.2 while as sample i tried is Version 3.3

Comment: Going down to the code of Charts(3.2.1) I found out that values are not rendered if drawIconsEnabled is false, removing that line the values are visible. Also on version 3.3 I can see the values even if drawIconsEnabled is false.

Comment: Thanks alot. It worked with drawIconsEnabled answer. Kindly post this answer and I shall mark as answer. Once again thanks alot

Comment: Also kindly help me in appending $ symbol to every value.

Comment: To add the $ symbol you will have to use a custom value formatter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813899/ios-charts-valueformatter